# How to iterate in url and find specific character in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a below URLs and I want to iterate in it but I want to start in "Test" location. If there is no "Test" then I will skip it.

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project1/Test/newfolder
https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/BudgetTracking/Test/folder1
https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project3/Subfolder
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your expected output for these 3 sample urls?

Comment: You don't need to iterate. You can use any of the `String` members to find `Test` and read the rest of the string, or use a regex and capture everything after `Test/`

Comment: Please show sample input and output. Are those urls stored as strings in a list? If so, please show the full definition of the list. Also what specific character are you trying to find, and what do you want to do when you find it? This is very hard to provide a good answer other than *"take a look at `string.Contains`, `string.IndexOf`, `string.Split`, etc."* What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you want to iterate though each element or Do you want string after `Test/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the small amount of information you've provided, you can use the `IndexOf` method to get the staring index of a string within a string. Then we can use the `Substring` method to get the string that begins with the search term.

For example:

```
var urls = new List<string>
{
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project1/Test/Subfolder",
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/BudgetTracking/Test/Subfolder",
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project3/Subfolder",
};

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    var testIndex = url.IndexOf("Test", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (testIndex == -1) continue;
    var stringToSearch = url.Substring(testIndex);

    Console.WriteLine($"We will search for our character in this string: {stringToSearch}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for. Basically I want to know if there is "Test" folder after the top level folders like "project1" or  "BudgetTracking"

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>
{
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project1/Test/Subfolder",
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/BudgetTracking/Test/Subfolder",
    "https://sharepoint.com/sites/documentlibrary/project3/Subfolder",
};

foreach (string urlWithTest in urls.Where(url => url.Contains("Test")))
{
    string partialUrl = urlWithTest.Substring(urlWithTest.IndexOf("Test"));
    //Do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking but you can check to see if Test exists in each url in a foreach or whatever you want to use and then return whatever is after Test/

Something like this while iterating thru the URL's:

```
 string url = "https://blah.com/test/findme";
        if(url.Contains("/test"))
        {
            string toBeSearched = "/test";
            string code = url.Substring(url.IndexOf(toBeSearched) + toBeSearched.Length);


            Console.WriteLine(code);//This will write "/findme"
        }
```